# Captions of slider not visible (VPython)

Tags: python, 3d, slider, vpython

I have create a little 3d simulation with VPython. And with it sliders to control positions and colors or objects. However, I can't find a way to display a caption to indicate what is the slider about.

I have added an argument when defining the slider `wtitle`. I don't get any error message so I assume it is rightfuly defined but the caption is probably hidden or I am missing a step somewhere.

Here is my code:

```
""" Import libraries """

import vpython as vp
    
""" Create Canvas """

canvas = vp.canvas(width=1080, height=720)
scene = vp.scene

""" Create objects """

# Define the planet
planet_radius = 5
# planet_texture = 'planet.jpg'  # You can replace this with your own custom picture
planet = vp.sphere(radius=planet_radius, texture=vp.textures.earth, shininess=0)

def atm_opacity(wavelength):
    return atm_density * (550 / wavelength)**4

# Define the atmosphere
atm_thickness = 3.0  # You can modify this using a slide cursor
atm_density = 0.5  # You can modify this using a slide cursor
atm_radius = planet.radius+atm_thickness
atm = vp.sphere(radius=atm_radius, opacity=0.25)
atm.opacity_function = atm_opacity

# Define the light source

def light_color(wavelength):
    r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
    if wavelength >= 400 and wavelength < 440:
        r = -(wavelength - 440) / (440 - 400)
        b = 1.0
    elif wavelength >= 440 and wavelength < 490:
        g = (wavelength - 440) / (490 - 440)
        b = 1.0
    elif wavelength >= 490 and wavelength < 510:
        g = 1.0
        b = -(wavelength - 510) / (510 - 490)
    elif wavelength >= 510 and wavelength < 580:
        r = (wavelength - 510) / (580 - 510)
        g = 1.0
    elif wavelength >= 580 and wavelength < 645:
        r = 1.0
        g = -(wavelength - 645) / (645 - 580)
    elif wavelength >= 645 and wavelength <= 700:
        r = 1.0
    return vp.vector(r, g, b)

light_type = 'red'  # You can modify this using a drop-down menu
# light_wavelength = 550  # You can modify this using a slide cursor
light_size = 2  # You can modify this using a slide cursor
light_intensity = 1.0  # You can modify this using a slide cursor
pos_drift = 50
light_xpos = atm_radius+pos_drift
light_ypos = atm_radius+pos_drift
light_zpos = atm_radius+pos_drift
light_pos = vp.vector(light_xpos, light_ypos, light_zpos)
wavelength = 400
light = vp.local_light(pos=light_pos, color= light_color(wavelength), radius=light_size)
light.color_function = light_color


# Define the camera
scene.autoscale = False
scene.range = 10
scene.forward = vp.vector(0, 0, -1)
scene.up = vp.vector(0, 1, 0)
scene.caption = 'Click and drag on the light source to move it. Use the drop-down menu and slide cursors to adjust its properties.'

""" Define the event handlers """

def on_light_down(evt):
    global light_dragging, light_drag_pos
    light_dragging = True
    light_drag_pos = evt.pos

def on_light_move(evt):
    global light_dragging, light_drag_pos
    if light_dragging:
        light.pos += evt.pos - light_drag_pos
        light_drag_pos = evt.pos

def on_light_up(evt):
    global light_dragging
    light_dragging = False

# Bind the event handlers
vp.scene.bind('mousedown', on_light_down)
vp.scene.bind('mousemove', on_light_move)
vp.scene.bind('mouseup', on_light_up)

def on_mouse_down(event):
    global dragging, last_mouse_pos
    obj = scene.mouse.pick
    if obj == light:
        dragging = True
        last_mouse_pos = scene.mouse.pos

canvas.bind('mousedown', on_mouse_down)

# Create the slider to rotate the light source around
def set_rotation_angle(slider):
    # light.rotate(angle=slider.value, axis=vp.vector(0, 1, 0), origin=planet.pos)
    
    # Calculate the rotation angle
    angle = vp.radians(slider.value)
    
    # Calculate the new position of the object
    x = atm_radius+pos_drift * vp.cos(angle)
    y = 0
    z = atm_radius+pos_drift * vp.sin(angle)
    
    # Set the position of the object
    light.pos = vp.vector(x, y, z)

# Create the slider
slider = vp.slider(wtitle='Rotate light source', min=0, max=360, step=1, value=0, bind=set_rotation_angle)

# Create slider to change light source wavelength
def WL_cursor(slider):
    val = slider.value
    new_wavelength = light_color(val)
    global light
    light.color = new_wavelength
    
slider = vp.slider(wtitle='Change light source color', min=400, max=700, length=250, bind=WL_cursor)

# Define the white light button
def white():
    global light
    light.color = vp.color.white

# Create the exit button
white_button = vp.button(bind=white, text="White light")

""" Run the simulation """

while True:
    vp.rate(30)
    
    # Update the atmosphere
    atm.radius = planet.radius+atm_thickness
    atm.opacity = 0.25*atm_density
    
    # Update the light source
    light.radius = light_size
    light.intensity = light_intensity
    light.pos = light.pos

    # Update the camera
    vp.scene.center = planet.pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the sliders to the `scene` you need to add it to the `canvas` for some reason. So something like:

```
slider_angle = vp.slider(wtitle='Rotate light source', min=0, max=360, step=1, value=0, bind=set_rotation_angle, right=15)
canvas.append_to_caption('Slide the cursor to move the light source.')
canvas.append_to_caption('\n\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

VPython automatically creates a canvas named "scene" (or in your case "vp.scene"). You then say scene = vp.scene and you set various attributes of this canvas, such as scene.autoscale = False. But you also create a second canvas, named canvas: canvas = vp.canvas(...). The most of your program references the canvas named scene, but you bind "mousedown" to canvas, which is confusing. The cleanest way to proceed is to delete the creation of "canvas" and bind mousedown to scene.